# How to check that insertThenNext returns the inserted value if it's less than everything else in the tree

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue

i've tried a multitude of solutions including changing the way that insertThenNext deals with the numbers but all possible solutions i've tried end up making the code fail the other tests that it must pass. I have asked multiple people and have looked online with no help this is really my last resort and any help is appreciated.

it has 7 checks that it must pass which are

1. Check that changePriority works correctly when it doesn't have to move anything.
2. Check that changePriority works correctly when it has to bubble up.
3. Check that changePriority works correctly when it has to bubble down.
4. Check that delete works correctly when it has to bubble down.
5. Check that delete works correctly when it has to bubble up.
6. Check that insertThenNext bubbles down correctly
7. Check that insertThenNext returns the inserted value if it's less than everything else in the tree

i have managed to get it to pass all checks besides the final test where i am receiving this output:

```
2
1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20,
```

when i should be receiving this output

```
1
2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20,
```

```
public class PriorityQueue {
    public class EmptyException extends RuntimeException {}

    private int[] items = new int[10];
    int size = 0;

    private static int leftChild(int index) { return 2 * index + 1; }
    private static int rightChild(int index) { return 2 * index + 2; }
    private static int parent(int index) { return (index - 1) / 2; }

    private void swap(int index1, int index2) {
        int temp = items[index1];
        items[index1] = items[index2];
        items[index2] = temp;
    }

    public void insert(int p) {
        if (size == items.length) {
            int[] newItems = new int[size * 2];
            System.arraycopy(items, 0, newItems, 0, size);
            items = newItems;
        }

        int cur = size;

        items[size++] = p;
        while (cur > 0 && items[cur] < items[parent(cur)]) {
            swap(cur, parent(cur));
            cur = parent(cur);
        }
    }

    public int next() throws EmptyException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyException();
        }

        int next = items[0];
        size--;

        items[0] = items[size];
        int cur = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (smallestInFamily(cur) == rightChild(cur)) {
                swap(cur, rightChild(cur));
                cur = rightChild(cur);
            } else if (smallestInFamily(cur) == leftChild(cur)) {
                swap(cur, leftChild(cur));
                cur = leftChild(cur);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return next;
    }

    private int smallestInFamily(int index) {
        int lc = leftChild(index);
        int rc = rightChild(index);

        if (rc < size && items[rc] < items[index] && items[rc] < items[lc]) {
            return rc;
        }
        if (lc < size && items[lc] < items[index]) {
            return lc;
        } else {
            return index;
        }
    }

    public int size() { return size; }
    public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }

    public void changePriority(int oldP, int newP) {
        int index = findNodeIndex(oldP);
        if (index != -1) {
            items[index] = newP;
            if (index > 0 && newP < items[parent(index)]) {
                bubbleUp(index);
            } else {
                bubbleDown(index);
            }
        }
    }

    public void delete(int p) {
        int index = findNodeIndex(p);
        if (index != -1) {
            items[index] = items[size - 1];
            size--;
            if (index < size) {
                if (index > 0 && items[index] < items[parent(index)]) {
                    bubbleUp(index);
                } else {
                    bubbleDown(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int insertThenNext(int p) {
        if (size == items.length) {
            // Resize the array to accommodate more elements
            int[] newItems = new int[size * 2];
            System.arraycopy(items, 0, newItems, 0, size);
            items = newItems;
        }

        int oldRoot = items[0];
        items[0] = p;
        bubbleDown(0);
        return oldRoot;
    }

    private int findNodeIndex(int value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (items[i] == value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void bubbleUp(int index) {
        while (index > 0 && items[index] < items[parent(index)]) {
            swap(index, parent(index));
            index = parent(index);
        }
    }

    private void bubbleDown(int index) {
        int maxIndex = index;

        int leftChild = leftChild(index);
        if (leftChild < size && items[leftChild] < items[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = leftChild;
        }

        int rightChild = rightChild(index);
        if (rightChild < size && items[rightChild] < items[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = rightChild;
        }

        if (index != maxIndex) {
            swap(index, maxIndex);
            bubbleDown(maxIndex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue();
        pq.insert(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // Initialize with a sentinel value

        int[] elementsToInsert = new int[] {6, 2, 14, 4, 10, 16, 13, 7, 15, 20};
        for (int i : elementsToInsert)
            pq.insertThenNext(i);

        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(pq.next() + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data demonstrating the problem, and explain what using a debugger showed as the first step things went awry.

Comment: sorry yes i should've mentioned that It runs without an error but it has 7 checks that it must pass which are 

1) Check that changePriority works correctly when it doesn't have to move anything.
2) Check that changePriority works correctly when it has to bubble up.
3) Check that changePriority works correctly when it has to bubble down.
4) Check that delete works correctly when it has to bubble down.
5) Check that delete works correctly when it has to bubble up.
6) Check that insertThenNext bubbles down correctly

Comment: 7) Check that insertThenNext returns the inserted value if it's less than everything else in the tree

i have managed to get it to pass all checks besides the final test where i am receiving this output,   

2
1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20,

when i should be receiving 1
2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20,

Comment: its hard to structure it in the comments here so im going to try and add it to the original post

Comment: When I run this code, the output is just `20,`.

Comment: Your `insertThenNext` doesn't change the size of your priority queue. Also, why are you expecting `1` to show up in your output when your input array doesn't contain a `1` at all?